# Android: display data from remote database in gridview instead of listview (Convert ListView to GridView)

Tags: android, database, gridview, android-listview

I'm new to android and have been working with an AndroidHive Tutorial which loads in a list of "products" from a remote database and displays it in a listview. I have the tutorial running and it's very good, but I want to modify it display the data in a gridview instead of a listview and am not sure how to. Here's the code I'm working with.

```
public class TimeTableActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> modulesList;

// url to get all modules list
private static String url_all_modules = "  http://<MyIPAddress>/timetable/get_all_modules.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MODULES = "modules";
private static final String TAG_MODID = "modid";
private static final String TAG_MODULE_NAME = "module_name";
private static final String TAG_DAY = "day";


//   modules JSONArray
JSONArray modules = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.time_table);


// Hashmap for ListView
modulesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// Loading modules in Background Thread
new LoadAllmodules().execute();

GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.mygrid);

// on seleting single product
// launching Edit Product Screen
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {





        // Starting new intent
        //Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
        //  TimeTableActivity.class);
        // sending modid to next activity
        //in.putExtra(TAG_MODID, modid);

        // starting new activity and expecting some response back
        //startActivityForResult(in, 100);
    }


});

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
// if result code 100
if (resultCode == 100) {
    // if result code 100 is received 
    // means user edited/deleted product
    // reload this screen again
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllmodules extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

/**
 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(TimeTableActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading Time Table. Please wait...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}

/**
 * getting All modules from url
 * */
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_modules, "GET", p arams);

    // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
    Log.d("ALL MODULES: ", json.toString());

    try {
        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1) {
            // modules found
            // Getting Array of modules
            modules = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MODULES);

            // looping through All modules
            for (int i = 0; i < modules.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = modules.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_MODID);
                String day = c.getString(TAG_DAY);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_MODULE_NAME);



                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_MODID, id);
                map.put(TAG_DAY, day);
                map.put(TAG_MODULE_NAME, name);


                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                modulesList.add(map);
            }
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Time Table cannot be displayed right now",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // no modules found
            // Launch Add New product Activity
            //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            //      NewProductActivity.class);
            // Closing all previous activities
            //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            //startActivity(i);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all modules
    pDialog.dismiss();
    // updating UI from Background Thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */

 GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.mygrid);

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    TimeTableActivity.this, modulesList,
                    R.layout.tt_item, new String[] {     TAG_MODID, TAG_DAY,
                            TAG_MODULE_NAME},
                    new int[] { R.id.modid, R.id.day,     R.id.name});

            // updating listview
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });

}
}}
```

<----- XML tt_item ------> assuming I don't have to modify this

```
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/modid"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:visibility="gone" />


<!-- Name Label -->
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/day"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:paddingTop="6dip"
 android:paddingLeft="6dip"
 android:textSize="17sp"
 android:textStyle="bold" />

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/name"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:paddingTop="6dip"
 android:paddingLeft="6dip"
 android:textSize="17sp"
 android:textStyle="bold" />
```

<----XML time_table -----> assuming I will just have to change to a standard gridview

```
 <GridView
 android:id="@+id/mygrid"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:numColumns="2"
 android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

Any help would be very much appreciated as I'm really not sure how to go about solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. You have to do some changes, as follows:

- change `ListActivity` to `Activity`
- init a GridView variable as `GridView grid;`
- this `ListView lv = getListView();` should be `grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.mygrid)`
  So `lv.setOnItemClickListener(...)` should be `grid.setOnItemClickListener(...)`
- then, this `setListAdapter(adapter);` become `grid.setAdapter(adapter)`
- finally, your layout is:

  ```
  <GridView
       android:id="@+id/mygrid"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:numColumns="2"
       android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
  ```

You can choose the width of a column with `android:columnWidth` and its number with `android:numColumns`. As `android:stretchMode` is for control how items are stretched to fill their space. You can find a simple tutorial on the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).
Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT:**

You <strike>always</strike> need to use `findViewById` method inside `onCreate` method not *before*. Use this:

```
public class TimeTableActivity extends Activity {

    // init a variable
    GridView grid;

    // Then, in onCreate method find its id
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.time_table);

         // find the view
         grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.mygrid);

   }
   // ...

   // Finally, in onPostExecute method, reuse the SAME variable as above
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
       // ...
       // reuse *grid*
       grid.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

findViewById() can be called inside other methods like `onAttach`, `onDestroy`, etc  - *(sorry for my grammar mistake)*. Therefore, as your code above, you can avoid to create a var. So you just have to  do this *(faster in a way)*:

```
( (GridView) findViewById(R.id.mygrid) ).setAdapter(adapter); // simply
```

inside onPostExecute().

Comment: Thanks for the response, got a force close with those modifications unfortunately.

Comment: Can you update your code into your question and also add your LogCat please. I'll try to help you with your error. - I updated my answer, you should create a init variable to set your adapter after in postexecute, this can avoid to have a NullPointerException error.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Fllo for your help, I undated my question with the code you gave me and it's working perfect now. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @GrahamKill Glad to help, however it's better to use a variable as you can see in my update. This avoids you to reuse again and again the `findViewById` method.

Comment: Okay I understand. I'll try and modify it again to work better. Thanks again.